# Break of Dawn, Meridia’s Beacon glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’m on the quest ‘The Break of Dawn’, the one that Meridia gives you. Instead of getting the beacon and going to her shrine, I went to her shrine and she gave me the quest. A quest marker didn’t pop up, so I used the clairvoyance spell. It led me to Dawnstar, and southeast up the hill, but when I got to the top, it led me back down the hill, and then back up. It keeps on happening and it won’t stop. I’ve fast traveled away, then came back.

Where should I go?

Answer (score -2):

Never mind. I just traveled to Solstheim it’s southwest of the temple of Miraak.